# Why does this json_encoded string NOT return the fourth element?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm trying to echo a simple json_encoded file.

```
<?php
$allMessages = file_get_contents("chatmessages.txt");

$allMessagesArr = explode(PHP_EOL, $allMessages);
$newObj = [];
var_dump($allMessagesArr);
foreach ($allMessagesArr as $thisLine) {
    // echo($thisLine . "\n");
    if (empty($thisLine) ) {

    } else {
        $thisLineArr = explode("|", $thisLine);

        $newObj[trim($thisLineArr[0])] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);
        // echo("here comes another one ".$thisLineArr[0] . " : ". $thisLineArr[1]."\n");
    }
}
$newObjForFront = json_encode($newObj);
echo($newObjForFront);
```

chatmessages.txt looks like this

```
bob|hello
jimmy|second try incoming again
sam|third try

bob|oh damn
```

I've echoed each individual line within the loop and the fourth element appears.  However, when I echo $newObjForFront, it's missing the last element.  Any ideas why?

Comment: `$newObj[trim($thisLineArr[0])] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);` this line will replace value with the last message of any username. if any username have multiple messages then only last message will be stored in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your final array `$newObj` in

```
$newObj[trim($thisLineArr[0])] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);
```

Your using the name as the index to the array.  As array indexes have to be unique, this means in fact the last entry overwrites the first one, so your actual output is...

```
{"bob":"oh damn","jimmy":"second try incoming again","sam":"third try"}
```

So it is in fact the first message that is missing.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to just have all of the messages, then you could store them using

```
$newObj[] = [ "user"=> trim($thisLineArr[0]), "msg" =>trim($thisLineArr[1])];
```

Which would give you the output as...

```
[{"user":"bob","msg":"hello"},{"user":"jimmy","msg":"second try incoming again"},{"user":"sam","msg":"third try"},{"user":"bob","msg":"oh damn"}]
```

Comment: Another way is to make array of messages for a user: `$newObj[trim($thisLineArr[0])][] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);`.

Comment: @Syscall - I considered that, but it doesn't maintain the order of the messages.  So this depends on what OP wants to do with the data.  The edit I put on encodes them with all of the messages in order.

Answer (score 0):

`$newObj[trim($thisLineArr[0])] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);` this line will replace value with the last message of any username. if any username have multiple messages then only last message will be stored in the array.

By creating multidimensional you can store multiple messages with the same username. Check below code that may help you

```
$newObj[][trim($thisLineArr[0])] = trim($thisLineArr[1]);
```